# Get Color(Pixel) information on onTouch (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to get color of a pixel say (x,y) and check if its red and if it is red then send a touch event.

I want it to run in background and it should always be checking the color of that pixel (x,y) and as soon as it turns red , a touch event should be simulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from the following example.

```
final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);


            int red = Color.red(pixel);
            int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int green = Color.green(pixel);        
            return false;
        }
   });
```

Comment: note that ImageView width and height must be wrap_content.

Comment: @Murtaza I think you got me wrong there.
I do not want to get color of pixel on onTouch, What I want is to keep a check on a particular pixel and when its color changes a touch event should be simulated.

Comment: well there is simple logic here. you can record the x and y position with r,g and b color codes, and compare with values on time interval, interval can be possible through many ways like AlarmManager and TimerTask