# android how to get the color name under touch of imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have seen different cases and links over the stackoverflow and others , but unable to find the answer according to my needs.

I have simple activity , on which I am drawing on canvas, but in front I have placed an Image and on there I have different color.

Now I  was looking for the color, I was trying to check on touch of that imageview that what color is touched.

> So my  question is that , **can I get the name of color whcih is
>       under touch by the user. For example if he touch the Black ,then I
>       print the toast that you have touched the black color**.??

please help me in this , I want to get the names of color.

Comment: what do you mean by color's name?

Comment: I mean , if I touch black , it should tell me about the color name , that it is black]

Comment: well you should map 2^24  int values to a String.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break the task into multiple subtasks.

1. Determining the color of [the pixel at the point pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271857/get-colorpixel-information-on-ontouch-android).
2. A [comparison of the pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors) to the table names. ([like this](http://www.color-hex.com/color-names.html) or
   [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp))