# Android image replace colour at touch

Tags: android, replace, colors, imageview, rgb

I have an android app in which I am loading an imageview from gallery. This is typically that of any interior of a room. I have loaded the image in a canvas. Then what I am intending to do is - I will touch any point on the imageview. The color which I am  touching(I am able to get the RGB value) should be replaced throughout that image with another color - say RED.It should be evenly replaced in the image. Now I am able to precisely replace the touched RGB color with RED, but it is appearing as splattered. What I want is wherever the touched color or its nearby hues appear in the image, it should be evenly replaced with - say RED. Please help me out in this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the task into multiple subtasks.

1. Determining the color of [the pixel at the point pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271857/get-colorpixel-information-on-ontouch-android).
2. Replace all [similar pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors) with a certain shift.

About how to replace the pixels are [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237915/replace-black-color-in-bitmap-with-red). Shift you should get from comparison formula.

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by shifting the pixels?

Comment: Color 120 -> 125; Color 122-> 127; Color 121-> 126; Etc

Comment: Thanks for your guidance so far. One last hurdle. I see in the post for shifting pixels -lots of comments and it was quite confusing. Can you please help me in in identifying a proper solution? What should I do with the lab value? How can I replace the lab value with red? Any help in this will be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I gave a link to an example of the replacement color. There is an entire function.

Comment: No I was referring to the pixel shift example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors. The details in that are quite elaborate and I am not able to comprehend that.

Comment: return (
             Math.abs(_rA - da) <= (255 - tolerance) &&
             Math.abs(_rR - dr) <= tolerance &&
             Math.abs(_rG - dg) <= tolerance &&
             Math.abs(_rB - db) <= tolerance
             );

Comment: What is rA da, rR dr etc. and what value of tolerance. Sorry if i am troubling you too much, coz i am a novice to these concepts.